# byte literal array to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python, I am calling an external service and printing the data which is basically byte literal array.

```
results = q.sync('([] string 2#.z.d; `a`b)')

print(results)
[(b'2018.06.15', b'a') (b'2018.06.15', b'b')]
```

To Display it without the `b`, I am looping through the elements and decoding the elements but it messes up the whole structure.

```
for x in results:
    for y in x:
        print(y.decode())

2018.06.15
a
2018.06.15
b
```

Is there a way to covert the full byte literal array to string array (either of the following) or do I need to write a concatenate function to stitch it back?

```
('2018.06.15', 'a') ('2018.06.15', 'b')  
(2018.06.15,a) (2018.06.15,b)
```

something like the following (though I want  to avoid this approach )

```
for x in results:
    s=""
    for y in x:
        s+="," +y.decode()
    print(s)

,2018.06.15,a
,2018.06.15,b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the previous answer, your command should be as follows:
This code will result in a list of tuples.

```
[tuple(x.decode() for x in item) for item in result]
```

The following code will return tuples:

```
for item in result:
     t = ()
     for x in item:
             t = t + (x.decode(),)     
     print(t)
```

Comment: Thanks @luz , is there a way to make it like `('2018.06.15', 'a') ('2018.06.15', 'b') `

Comment: You mean not being inside a list? I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line, which gives you back a list of decoded tuples.

```
[tuple(i.decode() for i in y) for x in result for y in x]
```

Comment: it throws an error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: You've got too many nested comprehensions, `i` is the individual bytes of the byte array.